# How to Handle POPUP browser in Selenium2(Webdriver)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webbrowser-control

I'm using Selenium2 (Webdriver).

Well, I have a Problem.

I have a A Browser.
 When I click one button in A Browser,  Another popup browser(B) is open.

And, The process what I have to do  in B browser is done, B browser wasn't close.
But, this is not my problem. B browser is originally Designed this way.

my problem is ..

After B browser's process is finished, when I tried to find out C element in A browser, So B browser wans't closeed, that I can't find out C element. because Selenium tried to find out C element in B browser.

I just want...

When I do something in Browser B, Browser B has a Handle.
and the Process in Browser is done, the handle must moving in A Browser.

How can I? Please Help me.

Comment: You need to switch window to other browser window handle before finding element C in Browser A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code for switching between the Windows:
With windows handle we can switch between windows.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
//First navigating to Yahoo site
driver.get("http://www.Yahoo.com");
//Capturing the window handle
String strMainWindowHandle=driver.getWindowHandle();
//For better understanding printing the page title
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

//Now opening a new window
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"n");
Set<String> winHandles=driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String handle:winHandles)
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
//Navigating to Google site with new window i.e new window handle 
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
//For better understanding printing the page title
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

//Switching back control to main Window which captured earlier
driver.switchTo().window(strMainWindowHandle);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Once you come back to your main window handle you can perform Click or whatever u want.